# System of Ordinary differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the system $$\frac{dx}{dt}=(1+x^{2})y$$ $$\frac{dy}{dt}=-(1+x^{2})x,t\in\mathbb{R.}$$ With initial condition $(x(0),y(0))=(a,b)$ ,Then the system has solution

$1.$ Only if $(a,b)=(0,0)$

$2.$ For all $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$

$3.$ Such that $x^{2}(t)+y^{2}(t)=a^{2}+b^{2},t\in\mathbb{R.}$

My attempt is as

Dividing second equation by one we get $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}$$ and solving we get $$x^{2}+y^{2}=c$$ where $c$ is arbitrary constant. Now applying initial conditions we get $x^{2}+y^{2}=a^{2}+b^{2}$ , so according to me i found option $3$rd is  correct. Am i right in my calculation? Please suggest me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is option 2 wrong? You did not show anything about it.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat     In answer key it is given correct. But i din't know how?

Comment: Which one is given correct?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat    $2$nd and $3$rd...

Comment: Should be since the solution obtained is satisfied by all real $a,b$.

Comment: my method to handling the problem is correct or there is some mistake in the way??

Comment: Its okay. No problem with it.